# Correct way to save pinging other email server's while bulk emailing?

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta, bulk, bulk-email

This is what I am planing to do with my email table . I have setup Postfix on same server .

Separate email column into two columns for example

user@gmail.com

get separated into

```
Username  |  Hostname
          |
user      |  gmail.com
```

Now  fetching data from database I do sql query order by `hostname`

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $data[$row['hostname']][] = $row['username'] . '@' . $row['hostname'];
}

foreach($data as $hostname => $emails)
{
     $list = implode(',',$emails);

      mail($list,'This is subject','Some message');
}
```

Will doing this save me from pinging each server (like yahoo,google) multiple times ?

Comment: What meaning do you assign to your _quite_ non-standard usage of "pinging"?

Comment: @lanzz when my server MTA contacts some other server MTA to transport mail is what I mean by pinging here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any control over the email delivery from your PHP script. The `mail()` function only passes the message to your [configured transport mechanism](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) and leaves it to handle the delivery however it is configured to. Sorting your `mail()` calls by hostname gives you no advantage at all.

On the Postfix end, you might want to read about [SMTP connection caching](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp), which seems to pipeline multiple email deliveries over the same connection.